# Laravel How to sum DB query with substring?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to sum with substring in laravel like this sql.
(My model name is `Fgbarcode`) Thanks for help me T^T

```
SELECT SUM(substr(fg_code, 22,14)) AS fg_code
FROM fg_barcode group BY substr(fg_code,2,3);
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `eloquent model` you are able to utilize DB raw to achieve these custom `mysql` queries.

```
FgBarcode::
    select(DB::raw('SUM(substr(fg_code, 22,14)) AS fg_code'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('substr(fg_code,2,3)'));
```